# ORA-00923 - FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00923

I'm getting this error message "FROM keyword not found where expected." What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT department_id
FROM employees
HAVING MIN(salary) < (SELECT MIN(salary)
         WHERE department_id < 60)
GROUP BY department_id;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your `Having` clause should be after `group by`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a from in the line:

```
SELECT MIN(salary)
         WHERE department_id < 60
```

It needs to be

```
SELECT MIN(salary) FROM {TABLENAMEHERE}
         WHERE department_id < 60
```

For the complete query:

```
SELECT department_id
FROM employees
GROUP BY department_id
HAVING MIN(salary) < (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM {TABLENAMEHERE}
         WHERE department_id < 60);
```

Comment: I also put the group by before the having as Annjawn suggested above.